# htaccess - only rewrite if "/" (Slash) contained

Tags: .htaccess

I am having some issues with Apache rewriting rules.

On my webserver the following files with a leading "`s`" exist (exerpt):

```
search.php
stats.php
status.php
```

Now, i want to rewrite `search.php` to simply `s`.
But when i now call `status.php`, my `search.php` is being included.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^stats$ stats.php
RewriteRule ^status$ status.php
RewriteRule ^s search.php        #  <---
RewriteRule ^live$ live.php
RewriteRule ^about$ about.php
RewriteRule ^i$ item.php
RewriteRule ^compare$ compare.php
DirectoryIndex home.php
```

How can i force Apache to only rewrite `search.php` to `s` if the URL is like

```
http://localhost/s/PARAM1/...
```

I tryed `RewriteRule ^s/ search.php` without success.
**EDIT:** 404 Error at `.../s/PARAM1/...`, `stats`, etc. works.

I hope you'll understand my issue although I'm not very familiar with the rewriting rules.

Comment: What error did you get for `RewriteRule ^s/ search.php` rule?

Comment: I'm getting a 404 Error.

Comment: I think your project name is missing in the url, you should have something like : `http://localhost/myproject/s`

Comment: Naa, "localhost" is just an example. I didn't want to post the real URL because it looks like advertisement

Comment: Post your complete .htaccess in question

Comment: can you post your project structure

Answer (score 0):

Reorder your rules and make use of regex to reduce your rules like this:

```
DirectoryIndex home.php
RewriteEngine on

# skip all files and directories from rewrite rules below
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^(statu?s|live|about|compare)$ $1.php [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^i$ item.php [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^s/ search.php [L,NC]
```